# Read and return all values from an array

Tags: matplotlib

**Elaborated question:**

Let me clarify my question. I want to plot a list of array output as a 2D scatter plot with polarity along x axis subjectivity along y axis and modality values that ranges between -1 and 1 determines the type of marker( o,x, ^, v)

output

```
polarities:  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
subjectivity:  [ 0.1  0.   0.   0. ]
modalities:  [ 1.   -0.25  1.    1.  ]
```

The modified code with limited marker value for 2 range.

```
print "polarities: ", a[:,0]
print "subjectivity: ", a[:,1]
print "modalities: ", a[:,2]

def markers(r):
    markers = np.array(r, dtype=np.object)
    markers[(r>=0)] = 'o'
    markers[r<0] = 'x'
    return markers.tolist()

def colors(s):
    colors = np.array(s, dtype=np.object)
    colors[(s>=0)] = 'g'
    colors[s<0] = 'r'
    return colors.tolist()

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(a[:,0], a[:,1], marker = markers(a[:,2]), color= colors(a[:,0]), s=100, picker=5)
```

My intent is to check the modality value and return one of the four markers.
if  I hardcore 'o' it returns the plot.

```
 ax.scatter(a[:,0], a[:,1], marker = markers('o'), color= colors(a[:,0]), s=100, picker=5)
```

As a trial i tried to mimic the color function and pass it as a[:,2] but hit a shell output error

```
ValueError: Unrecognized marker style ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o']
```

The question  is: Is my approach wrong? or how to make it recognize the marker style?

**Edit1**

Trying to get the m value between 0 and .5

with this code

```
ax.scatter (p[0<m<=.5], s[0<m<=.5], marker = "v", color= colors(a[:,0]), s=100, picker=5)
```

yields this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How to range m value between 0 and .5  in the example given in answer 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but I assume your array `a` is of shape `(N,3)` and so your arrays `s` and `r` are actual arrays and not scalars.

First off, you cannot have several markers with one call of `scatter()`. If you want your plot to have several markers, you'll have to slice your array correctly and do several `scatter()` for each of your markers.

Regarding the colors, your problem is that your function `colors(r)` only return one color where it should return an array of colors (with the same number of elements as `a[:,0]`). Like such:

```
def colors(s):
    colors = np.array(s, dtype=np.object)
    colors[(s>0.25)&(s<0.75)] = 'g'
    colors[s>=0.75] = 'b'
    colors[s<=0.25] = 'r'
    return colors.tolist()

a = np.random.random((100,))
b = np.random.random((100,))

plt.scatter(a,b,color=colors(b))
```

**ANSWER TO YOUR EDIT 1:**

You seem to be on the right track, you'll have to do as many `scatter()` calls as you have markers.

Your error comes from the slicing index `[0<m<=.5]` which you cannot use like that. You have to use the full notation `[(m>0.)&(m<=.5)]`

Comment: Thanks. Please see elaborate question.

Comment: @Programmer_nltk I've answered your EDIT 1 problem. I believe you have everything you need to solve your problem from here

Answer (score 1):

As Diziet pointed out, `plt.scatter()` cannot handle several markers. You therefore need to make one scatter plot per marker-category. This can be done my conditioning on the property which should be reflected by the marker. In this case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = np.array( [ 0. ,  0.2 ,  -0.3 ,  0.2] )
s = np.array( [ 0.1,  0.,   0.,   0.3 ] )
m = np.array( [ 1.,   -0.25,  1. ,  -0.6  ] )


colors = np.array([(0.8*(1-x), 0.7*x, 0) for x in np.ceil(p)])

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter(p[m>=0], s[m>=0], marker = "o", color= colors[m>=0], s=100)
ax.scatter(p[m<0], s[m<0], marker = "s", color= colors[m<0], s=100)

ax.set_xlabel("polarity")
ax.set_ylabel("subjectivity")

plt.show()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were not just asking one question after the other but tried to come up with a solution based on what you already know. In this case the answer to how you select indizes based on multiple conditions has actually already been given in Diziet's answer.

Comment: Really appreciate the comment. Problem is I am very new to matplotlib so experimenting on the input given by others by trial and error. I will try for the solution. Thanks.